# After modifying attributes on a node.js vm context (sandbox), the modifications aren't seen by code in the context

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, jasmine

## Background

I'm working on [tests](https://github.com/nilbus/Backbone.dualStorage/tree/tests/spec) for the [Backbone.dualStorage](https://github.com/nilbus/Backbone.dualStorage) plugin for Backbone.js that replaces Backbone.sync.

This is a browser plugin, but I'm using jasmine-node to test it. I load the coffeescript source into the node environment to simulate the browser `window` using vm.createContext:

```
vm = require 'vm'
fs = require 'fs'
coffee = require 'coffee-script'
backboneDualstoragePath = './backbone.dualstorage.coffee'
source = fs.readFileSync(backboneDualstoragePath, 'utf8')
window = require('./global_test_context.coffee').window
context = vm.createContext window
coffee.eval source, sandbox: context, filename: backboneDualstoragePath
exports.window = context
```

This works great - in my tests, I can access `window.foo`, where foo is an attribute exported on the window object in global_test_context.coffee.

I can use Jasmine spies on and redefine methods on any object nested under the window sandbox. Eg:

```
spyOn(window.Store.prototype, 'create').andReturn(true)
window.Store.create() # The spy is called
window.localsync.create() # This function instantiates a Store object and calls create on it
                          # The spy is called
```

However if I try to spy on or otherwise modify the context's direct attributes, the change is not seen inside the sandbox context:

```
spyOn(window, 'localsync').andReturn(true)
window.localsync() # The spy is called
window.dualsync() # This function references the global localsync
                  # The original localsync is called
```

The [vm.createContext documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_createcontext_initsandbox) says:

> A (V8) context comprises a global object together with a set of
>   build-in objects and functions. The optional argument initSandbox
>   *will be shallow-copied to seed the initial contents of the global object* used by the context.

So it sounds like it copies the attributes from my window variable into the vm context. When I spy on or otherwise modify `window` after this point, I am working with the vm context, which I export as an attribute named `window`. Therefore I think that the paragraph above is irrelevant, but I wanted to include it in case I'm wrong.

## The Question

The flow of events boils down to this:

```
window = vm.createContext({globalVariables: forTesting...})

# similiar to vm.runInContext(backboneDualstorageSource, window)
coffee.eval(backboneDualstorageSource, sandbox: window)

# localsync and dualsync are both defined in the backboneDualstorageSource
spyOn(window, 'localsync')
window.dualsync() # calls the original localsync instead of the spy
```

Why is it that after modifying attributes on the vm context, references to those "global" attributes/functions inside the vm don't change? I want to understand this.

How can I work around this so that I can modify/spyOn globals in the browser script I'm testing?

Feel free to look at [the source](https://github.com/nilbus/Backbone.dualStorage/tree/tests/spec) to get a better idea of how things are actually written compared to the snippets in this question.

### Edit

I was able to work around this issue by creating the spy inside an eval that runs in the context, like the rest of the tested code. See https://github.com/nilbus/Backbone.dualStorage/commit/eb6c2b21

Could someone explain why I'm able to modify global variables within the context but not outside the context, even though I have access to them?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying context after eval is not affecting already evaluated scripts, if I understand your issue correctly. If you don't need to add new members to context, and just need to modify existing ones, use getters, which is working fine in latest node (0.8.x for now).

Comment: Are you suggesting something like `window.__defineSetter__('localsync', function(arg){ localsync = arg })` ?

Comment: I did that outside the eval context, and it didn't have any effect. Would you need to do it within the eval context?

Comment: Could you explain how and where you're suggesting I should be using getters? It's not clear at all from what you said.

Answer (score -1):

don't go down one level with the `global` key, try this:

```
window = vm.createContext({variablesForTesting.. })
```

Comment: The localsync and dualsync variables I'm testing are defined in the coffee source that I'm evaling.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? This isn't helpful as is.

Comment: You stated that `coffee.eval` is similar to `vm.runInContext`. And when using `vm.runInContext` the global object is defined directly by the `sandbox` parameter, not by a `sandbox.global` property. Sry if this wasn't helpful..

Comment: I see how my example misled you now; that global was actually just an example. I'm actually using the top level. I edited the example to hopefully clarify that it is an example.